# Answer Against Accepted Answer

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to submit my own answer due to not enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110630/unable-to-submit-my-own-answer-due-to-not-enough-reputation)

I have choosed or accepted wrong answer by oversight mistake and I realised it later that it was wrong choice but now I have a correct solution of my asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943518/establish-owner-on-new-instance-of-form). What I have to do?. The accepted wrong question could misguide someone hence I think I have to submit the correct answer of the same. If I submit the correct answer there than what about accepted answer?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can very well add another answer if you have a better solution.

It is also possible to change your mind on the selected answer, and just select another one. The green check mark will move to the new selection.

Comment: I am having less reputation then 100 hence I am not able to submit it right now.