# Unable to submit my own answer due to not enough reputation

Tags: support, answers, self-answer

I am unable to answer my own question due to not enough reputation. The question is:

- [Establish Owner On New Instance Of Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943518/establish-owner-on-new-instance-of-form)

I think if I am not allowed to answer the question then it will mislead someone because the answer I have accepted is wrong one and there are no other correct answers.

**So is it good to leave as it is?**

I think I made the mistake in hurry to accept it. Now I know the answer and want to post it, but the system does not allow to submit due to not enough reputation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always click on the check box again to remove the status as an accepted answer.

As a new user, I believe there's an 8-hour time limit for self-answering on questions. Once this limit has passed, you can submit your answer & accept it.